# How to access iOS notes with ifuse?

Tags: linux, synchronization, ios

I'm using [ifuse](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IOS#The_iFuse_Way) to sync my iOS device with Linux. Accessing photos (DCIM folder etc.) among other files and folders works, how can I access the notes though?

Comment: After searching through all of the folders and files, I haven't found anything related to notes. Though, I have used a number of windows apps like EaseUs which allow the user to access and download notes. Albeit, the free version has a limit of 10 files.